# Example of using Handlebars lookup helper

Tags: handlebars.js

[Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) has a built-in helper called `lookup`. The [documentation](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup) is not very clear about how it works. Could I see an example?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Sure, past me! Here's an example from your future.

Suppose you have an object or array `obj` and a variable `field` and you want to output the value of `obj[field]`, you would use the lookup helper `{{lookup obj field}}`.

The code defining the helper is simply:

```
function(obj, field) {
  return obj && obj[field];
}
```

Comment: Future you is right, you should accept this as the correct answer. Also, PM me next week's lottery results please.

Comment: Could you also show how to use the returned object?

Comment: [Bart S answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40160555/214517) is more complete, but I upvoted you too anyway for the gag. It's bad, I know, but I did. And I'm proud of it.

Answer (score 25):

The lookup property is useful if we don't know the name of the property we want, for instance because it's in a variable or the result of an expression.

If we have this object:

```
var book = {
    title: 'Discovery of Heaven'
};
```

We could put this in the HTML like this:

```
<p>{{book.title}}</p>
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
<p>{{lookup book 'title'}}</p>
```

Maybe we don't know that we want the title. Say the property name is somewhere in a variable instead:

```
var property = 'title';
```

Now we could show the book title like this:

```
<p>{{lookup book property}}</p>
```

Comment: This is a better description as the reference to arrays in the official docs and other answers is a bit of a red herring. You can further expand the train of thought by adding: `var property = 'authors'; {{#each (lookup book property)}}`