# How to use bracket notation of object in handlebar template?

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am creating an emberjs component from the route template attribute I am passing value to show in the template. But I am unable to access it in the component template by bracket notation of object.

```
//route.hbs
{{b-select 
    options=model.names
    valueProp='name'
}}
```

Model

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            names: [{name: 'abc'}, {name: 'xyz'}]
        });
    }

});
```

Component b-select hbs file

```
<select class="form-control" multiple={{multiple}}>
  {{#each options as |option|}}
    <option value="{{option}}">{{option[valueProp]}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

If I use `option.name` instead of `option[valueProp]` it works perfect. how I can dynamically pass the propery to select ? why the bracket notation is not working

Component JS file

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import fallbackIfUndefined from '../utils/computed-fallback-if-undefined';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    multiple: fallbackIfUndefined(false),
    options: fallbackIfUndefined(null),
    valueProp: fallbackIfUndefined(0),
    actions: {

    },
    didInsertElement() {
        //initialize jquery functions
        this.$('select').selectpicker({size: 6});
    },
    willDestroyElement() {
        //remove all events
    }
});
```

The error I am getting is

**Error: Parse error on line 3:
...alue="{{option}}">{{option[valueProp]}}<
-----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', got 'INVALID'**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [{{get}}](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_get) helper:

`<option value="{{option}}">{{get option valueProp}}</option>`

Answer (score -1):

You can use the handlebar lookup helper:

http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup

Try this:

```
<option value="{{option}}">{{lookup option valueProp}}</option>
```

Comment: why I am getting error. ember.debug.js:16628 Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: A helper named 'lookup' could not be found

Comment: hmm.. maybe you have an older version of ember. You can write the handlebar lookup helper yourself. It is quite simple. The helper code is mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829723/example-of-using-handlebars-lookup-helper.

Comment: I am using ember 2.4.2 still it is showing that error. is lookup depricated ? is it good idea to write helper for it ?

Comment: It's a Handlebars helper that is not available in Ember.