# Get data from an object via variable like javascript in handlebars

Tags: javascript, object, handlebars.js

is it possible to get the data from an object via a variable like in Javascript in handlebars?

For example you can do this in Javascript:

```
var objName = "test"
var obj = { test : {sortOrder: "asc"}, testNew : {sortOrder: "desc"}}
var sortOrder = obj[objName].sortOrder
```

Is this possible in handlebars? I know you can get the data if you write it without "objName":

```
{{obj.[test].sortOrder}}
```

I tried this:

```
{{obj.[objName].sortOrder}}
```

but i didn't get the data from my object. "objName" is already defined and the output from objName shows "test".

Maybe there is another way to get the data.

Greetings

BloodyGaia

Comment: why `{{objName.[objName].sortOrder}}` did your tried ?? should be `{{obj.[objName].sortOrder}}`

Comment: What you are looking for is the ["lookup" helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup). You would use it as: `{{lookup (lookup obj objName) 'sortOrder'}}`.

Comment: An explanation of how the lookup helper is used can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29829724/3397771).

Comment: @Mahi oh... you are right. it was obj.[objName].sortOrder which i tried.

Comment: @76484 thank you for the links i will try it later :-)